# Git diff between branch in pull request and last successful build of pipeline

Tags: bash, git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to get names of files that changed between current branch in pull request and last successful azure pipeline build. I set up pull request pipeline with script:

```
readonly url="https://dev.azure.com/----------/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(System.DefinitionId)&resultFilter=succeeded&statusFilter=completed&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending"

 response=$(curl -s -X GET -H "$authHeader" "$url")
 source_version=$(echo "$response" | jq -r '.value[0].sourceVersion')
 echo $source_version
 edited_files=$(git diff HEAD "$source_version" --name-only)
```

I'm trying to do diff between HEAD and commitId from last successful build of the pipeline, but this ends wit error: `fatal: bad object dabfadsfs58fc8aef4f8e34709f8e477084850ff7` The hash is valid commitId. Shallow copy is disabled. When I tried to run this pipeline outside pull request on main branch, then it worked but not in pull request.

What I do wrong? Is there better way to get this changes?

Comment: are you sure your git checkout contains the full repository? Git forges often use a shallow single branch checkout by default: in this case other braches or historical commits are not available.

In general I would suggest not using "last successful pipeline build" as the comparison point but "known good branch" instead: see e.g. `git merge-base main HEAD` if you need to know the actual forking point commit

Answer (score 0):

In Azure pipeline, by default, the checkout task will only check out the latest one source version (commit) which triggered the current pipeline run. In this situation, the git diff will not find the old commits from the source directory on agent.

To resolve this issue, you can set the **`fetchDepth`** to be **`0`** on the checkout task to fetch all history.

For example:

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
```

More details, see "[**Shallow fetch**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch)".

Comment: I stated in my question that this is already set.

Comment: Can you please provide the screenshots of your pipeline settings UI? And ensure the commit of latest successful build is contained in the commit history of the checked-out branch?